Does PostgreSQL has a VIP for master-slave replication?
Is there a VIP (Virtual IP) option available for PostgreSQL replication?
Specifically, in the event of a failover from the primary to the secondary, I’d like to avoid having to change the IP address in the application.
The VIP should always point to the primary node. For example, if the primary node is A, the VIP will point to A. If the primary node switches to B, the VIP will then point to B.

The IP address belongs to, and is managed by, the operating system. Why do you expect PostgreSQL to "have" it?

I was thinkg about something like SCAN from Oracle Database. We create a scan in Oracle grid infrastructure software

There are hardware switches that do that automatically when a server fails
